# Xdocument - Read value of attribute with Prefix

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

It is easy to find out value of Xdocument attribute but how do we find attribute with prefix/Namespace.

**XML code**

```
 <label:label xlink:type="resource" xlink:label="something" xlink:lang="en" xlink:id="res_4">My value</label:label>
```

I am trying to read attribute value xlink:Id (where p is XElement)

```
p => p.Attribute("xlink:id").Value
```

Which doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given you have declaration of the namespace prefix somewhere in the XML :

```
xmlns:xlink="dummy.url"
```

You can use `XNamespace` variable that point to above namespace URI to access an attribute in the namespace :

```
XNamespace xlink = "dummy.url";
.....
p => p.Attribute(xlink+"id").Value
//or simply cast the XAttribute to string 
//to avoid exception when the attribute not found in p
p => (string)p.Attribute(xlink+"id")
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`XName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xname(v=vs.110).aspx) class:

```
XName.Get("id", XLinkNamespaceName)
```

With `XLinkNamespaceName` the namespace with the prefix `xlink`.

To get the namespace from a prefix, you can use: [`XElement.GetNamespaceOfPrefix()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.getnamespaceofprefix(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
p => p.Attribute(p.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("xlink") + "id").Value
```

But I advise you not to work with prefixes in your C# code and use namespace instead. Indeed,

```
<myFile xmlns:myPrefix="http://www.tempUri.org/MyNamespace">
    <something myPrefix:myAttribute="myValue" />
</myFile>
```

Is "functionally" equivalent to:

```
<myFile xmlns:dfgerge="http://www.tempUri.org/MyNamespace">
    <something dfgerge:myAttribute="myValue" />
</myFile>
```

Comment: `XName xVal = XName.Get("id", "xlink"); string val = xelem.Attribute(xVal ).ToString();` Is this a correct way to use it?

Comment: @user2564977 Nope, xlink is the prefix, in your document you must have xmlns:xlink="..." where ... is the namespace.